# How to recover 2 results in the same function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function:

```
var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
var result1 = [];
var result2 = [];


for (var i = 0; i < query1.LRU.length; i++) {
  result1.push(formatName(query1.LRU[i], query1.Client[i], query1.round[i]));


}

for (var i = 0; i < query2.LRU.length; i++) {
  result2.push(formatName(query1.LRU[i], query1.Client[i], query1.round[i]));


}

return {
  result1: result1, 
  result2: result2
};

function formatName(lru, turnover, round) {
  return "[" + lru + "," + turnover + "," + round + "]";
}
```

It return the same values in `result1` and `result2`.
How can I recovre the values of the `result2`.

Can you help me please.
thank you.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. [This explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45717496/2427065)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a typo, in your second for loop you are taking values from query1 instead of query2

```
for (var i = 0; i < query2.LRU.length; i++) {
  result2.push(formatName(query1.LRU[i], query1.Client[i], query1.round[i]));//original
result2.push(formatName(query2.LRU[i], query2.Client[i], query2.round[i])); //change to this
}
```